# how to upgrade pip? getting this error while updating

Tags: python, pip

C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/b1/56a834acdbe23b486dea16aaf4c27ed28eb292695b90d01dff96c96597de/pip-20.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\winpython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2.dist-info\description.rst' -> 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-arh5ca_x-uninstall\program files\winpython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2.dist-info\description.rst'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 736, in install
requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
renames(path, new_path)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip\utils_*init*_.py", line 267, in renames
shutil.move(old, new)
File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\shutil.py", line 553, in move
os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\program files\winpython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pip-8.1.2.dist-info\description.rst'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 20.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+PermissionError+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a permission denied error. Run `command prompt` with administrative privileges (run as administrator). Then run the same pip upgrade command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the command in administrator mode? It feels like that would be the case since it says PermissionError.
Alternatively try running this:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: not working, getting same error. @mubin ansari